# about usercontrol usage

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, visual-sourcesafe, gacutil

I have created one usercontrol in vb.net 2005. and i have developed that usercontrol for my project & now i 'm using the source safe for sharing my project in my team. now when i'm using my userconteol then that time the dll of the usercontrol is deployed in the gac util but the gac util is only limited for the particular computer then my problem is how can i share my usercontrol dll in the source safe ?

thanxs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the assembly to VSS, but its not recommended, you can add the source to the VSS.

Comment: i'm not getting will u elaborate what u are saying.

Comment: You can add the user control assembly (dll) to VSS. But I dont think there is a direct way to install it to GAC. You may need some setup applications for this.